# Is is possible to plug a different version of .so file when debugging application on gdb?

Tags: gdb

I have a rtl simulation running, the simulator executable loads a number of shared objects. There is one such object which has definitions for various pli routines that are called during simulation.  I am interested in debugging a function in a particular `.so` file, let me say this is `routines.so`. I have compiled a version of `routines.so` with debug support. Now simulation is already running and I have attached gdb process to the simulator executable. It is picking up `routines.so` from the release area. I was wondering if there is a way to plug the `debug version of routines.so` in the current gdb session itself? I know that i could restart the simulation anytime and have the debug version picked up from the beginning, but these simulations take hours to get to the point of interest so I was just thinking if i can do on the fly replacement of a `routines.so`?

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering if there is a way to plug the debug version of routines.so in the current gdb session itself?

Not unless the simulator allows unloading and reloading of the `routines.so`.

> these simulations take hours to get to the point of interest so I was just thinking if i can do on the fly replacement of a routines.so?

No. What you may be able to do is build a *release* version of `routines.so` *with* debug info:

```
gcc -g -fPIC -O2 routines.c -shared -o routines.so
```

(replace `-O2` with whatever flags were used to build the release version).

Then use `(gdb) add-symbol-file /path/to/release-g/routines.so $load_address` (replace `$load_address` with one you get from `(gdb) info shared routines.so`).

This will allow you to debug "point of interest" at source level. This isn't quite as good as debugging non-optimized version (code could jump around, variables may be optimized out, etc.), but much better than debugging at assembly level.

For the future, if you are on an ELF platform, you should build `routines.so` with [separate debuginfo files](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html), so you can always debug it.